# Как сохранять данные asset'ов при их редактировании в EditorWindow?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в проекте есть `asset`, который из себя представляет *serializable scriptable object*.

Его код очень простой:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScriptable : ScriptableObject {   
    public float gravity = .3f;
    public float plinkingDelay = .1f;
    public float storedExecutionDelay = .3f;    
}
```

Мне не составляет труда изменить значения у этого ассета через инспектор. Эти изменения сохраняются. И после перезагрузки *Unity* все значения остаются, как и нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот в моем кастомном окне `Editor Window` такое не получается. Хоть и все изменения, сделанные в окне, отображаются и в инспекторе, но, тем не менее, после перезагрузки *Unity* можно увидеть, что данные остались те, 
которые были до изменения мною. Т.е. те, которые были еще при первой загрузке приложения. Ничего не сохранилось :-(

вот два скрипта которые я применяю для папки `Editor`:

**первый** (вспомогательный) - код заменяет поля в инспекторе (которые на рисунке выше) на кнопку, при нажатии на которую вызывается окно `EditorWindow`.

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestScriptable))]
public class TestScriptableEditor : Editor {
  public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
    if (GUILayout.Button("Open TestScriptableEditor"))
      TestScriptableEditorWindow.Init();
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**второй код** (в котором проблема) - это как раз попытка изменить данные ассета:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class TestScriptableEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
    public static TestScriptableEditorWindow testScriptableEditorWindow;
    private TestScriptable testScriptable;

    [MenuItem("Window/TestTaskIceCat/TestScriptableEditor")]
    public static void Init() {
        // инициализируем окно, отображаем его и устанавливаем настройки
        testScriptableEditorWindow = GetWindow<TestScriptableEditorWindow>(false, "TestScriptableEditorWindow", true);
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Show();
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Populate();
    }

    // здесь происходит инициализация моего ассета
    // с которым буду проводить манипуляции
    void Populate() {
        Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(TestScriptable), SelectionMode.Assets);        
        if (selection.Length > 0) {
            if (selection[0] == null)
                return;

            testScriptable = (TestScriptable)selection[0];
        }
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        if (testScriptable == null) {
            /* здесь манипуляции в случае если мой ассет null */
            return;
        }

        // Здесь начинаются попытки изменить значения
        testScriptable.gravity = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Gravity:", testScriptable.gravity);
        testScriptable.plinkingDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Plinking Delay:", testScriptable.plinkingDelay);
        testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Stored Execution Delay:", testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay);
        // конец региона с изменениями значений
    }    

    void OnSelectionChange() { Populate(); Repaint(); }
    void OnEnable() { Populate(); }
    void OnFocus() { Populate(); }

}
```

---

Собственно вопросы: В чем может быть проблема? Как её решить?  Может я как-то не так загружаю ассет? Или что?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле все просто и сложно и еще раз просто одновременно.

Не смотря на то, что даже при изменении данных в окне вы видите их изменение в инспекторе - не значит, что они реально изменяются. Выглядит как будто все работает, но.....Лично я бы это списал на недоработку со стороны разрабов Unity)

Чтобы все работало - нужно воспользоваться несколькими вещами:

- [GUI.changed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-changed.html) - который вернет `true`, если какой-либо контрол изменил значение входных данных. С помощью него будем детектить изменилось что-то или нет.
- [Undo.RecordObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RecordObject.html) - который позволяет записать изменения в `Undo state`, позволяя отменить изменения используя `undo`
- [EditorUtility.SetDirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) (**!!!самое главное!!!**) - если в кратце, то эта команда помечает объект как "грязный" и поэтому требует сохранения. Подробнее можно почитать кликнув на ссылку.

Теперь все, что нужно, так это в конце метода `OnGUI()` записать

```
if (GUI.changed) {
    // записываем изменения над testScriptable в Undo
    Undo.RecordObject(testScriptable, "Test Scriptable Editor Modify"); 
    // помечаем тот самый testScriptable как "грязный" и сохраняем.
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(testScriptable); 
}
```

Т.е. в итоге код будет такой:

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class TestScriptableEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
 public static TestScriptableEditorWindow testScriptableEditorWindow;
 private TestScriptable testScriptable;

 [MenuItem("Window/TestTaskIceCat/TestScriptableEditor")]
 public static void Init() {
  // инициализируем окно, отображаем его и устанавливаем настройки
  testScriptableEditorWindow = GetWindow<TestScriptableEditorWindow>(false, "TestScriptableEditorWindow", true);
  testScriptableEditorWindow.Show();
  testScriptableEditorWindow.Populate();
 }

 // здесь происходит инициализация моего ассета
 // с которым буду проводить манипуляции
 void Populate() {
  Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(TestScriptable), SelectionMode.Assets);        
  if (selection.Length > 0) {
   if (selection[0] == null)
    return;

   testScriptable = (TestScriptable)selection[0];
  }
 }

 public void OnGUI() {
  if (testScriptable == null) {
    /* здесь манипуляции в случае если мой ассет null */
   return;
  }

  testScriptable.gravity = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Gravity:", testScriptable.gravity);
  testScriptable.plinkingDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Plinking Delay:", testScriptable.plinkingDelay);
  testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Stored Execution Delay:", testScriptable.storedExecutionDelay);
  
  // Магия по созранению данных
  if (GUI.changed) {
   // записываем изменения над testScriptable в Undo
   Undo.RecordObject(testScriptable, "Test Scriptable Editor Modify");
   // помечаем тот самый testScriptable как "грязный" и сохраняем.
   EditorUtility.SetDirty(testScriptable); 
  }
 }    
  
 void OnSelectionChange() { Populate(); Repaint(); }
 void OnEnable() { Populate(); }
 void OnFocus() { Populate(); }
}
```

Всё. Это было просто.

---

Теперь к сложному-простому.

`SetDirty` - это, конечно, хорошо. Однако начиная с версии > 5.3 этот метод будет признан устаревшим и, возможно, еще в более поздних - будет удален. Когда именно - неизвестно. Вместо него можно пробовать работать по-другому:

Все действия в кастомном эдиторе (Editor) и окне (EditorWindow) нужно проводить между вызовами:

```
serializedObject.Update()

// Тут код эдитора

serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()
```

где:

- [serializedObject.Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.Update.html) - некий рефреш значений сериализованного объекта
- [serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties.html) - сохранение всех изменений сериализованного объекта
- [serializedObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) - это объект, который получает доступ к сериализованным (сохраненным в сцену или в ассет в проекте) свойствам (полям) объекта (или нескольких), 
  который вы редактируете. Он применяется вкупе с:
- [SerializedProperty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) - свойства, которые будут доставаться из `serializedObject` будут иметь данный тип, например

  ```
  SerializedProperty myGravity = serializedObject.FindProperty("gravity");
  SerializedProperty myPlinkingDelay = serializedObject.FindProperty("plinkingDelay");
  ...
  и т.д.
  ```
- [SerializedObject.FindProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.FindProperty.html) - находит свойство по его имени.
- [EditorGUILayout.PropertyField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PropertyField.html) - создает поле для `SerializedProperty`.

Последние четыре штуки как раз таки как `SetDirty` - пометит модифицируемый объект и сцену как "грязный" и создаст `Undo state` для вас.

Если уложить все в голове, то получится примерно следующее:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class TestScriptableEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
    public static TestScriptableEditorWindow testScriptableEditorWindow;
    private TestScriptable testScriptable;
    // объявляем наш сериализованный объект, с которым будем работать в итоге
    private SerializedObject serializedObj;

    [MenuItem("Window/TestTaskIceCat/TestScriptableEditor")]
    public static void Init() {
        testScriptableEditorWindow = GetWindow<TestScriptableEditorWindow>(false, "TestScriptableEditorWindow", true);
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Show();
        testScriptableEditorWindow.Populate();
    }

    // здесь происходит инициализация моего ассета
    // с которым буду проводить манипуляции
    void Populate() {
        Object[] selection = Selection.GetFiltered(typeof(TestScriptable), SelectionMode.Assets);
        if (selection.Length > 0) {
            if (selection[0] == null)
                return;

            testScriptable = (TestScriptable)selection[0];
            //инициализируем serializedObj, с которым будем работать
            serializedObj = new SerializedObject(testScriptable);
        }
    }

    // наши преобразования
    public void OnGUI() {
        if (testScriptable == null) {
             /* здесь манипуляции в случае если мой ассет null */
            return;
        }

        // начинаем наши манипулиции
        // лучше это делать перед началом отрисовки свойств
        serializedObj.Update();
        //получаем непосредственно нужное свойство из ассета и отрисовываем поле со значением
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObj.FindProperty("gravity"), new GUIContent("Gravity"), true);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObj.FindProperty("plinkingDelay"), new GUIContent("Plinking Delay"), true);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObj.FindProperty("storedExecutionDelay"), new GUIContent("Stored Execution Delay"), true);
        // Применяем изменения
        serializedObj.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    void OnSelectionChange() { Populate(); Repaint(); }
    void OnEnable() { Populate(); }
    void OnFocus() { Populate(); }
}
```

Итак, простота заключается в том, что всего лишь надо вызвать

`Update` → действия → `ApplyModifiedProperties`.

А сложность заключается в том, что придется танцевать с бубном вокруг кучи классов по работе со свойствами: `FindProperty`, `PropertyField` и `SerializedProperty`. Но если с этим моментом разобраться - становится всё просто :-)

Comment: А что если у меня в моем классе есть массив этапов Stage[] stages, с помощью которых я в моем editorWindow хочу создать нодовую систему, как мне сохранять изменения в массиве, которые я делаю например путем перестановки нодов, не отображая его в кастомном окне также как в инспекторе?