# ScriptableObject не сохраняет данные после перезагрузки Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor

Есть некий EquipmentData, в котором хранятся данные для экипировки:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class EquipmentData
{

    [SerializeField] private string _itemName;
    [SerializeField] private ItemType _itemType;
    [TextArea]
    [SerializeField] private string _itemDescription;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite _itemUiImage;
    [SerializeField] private int _itemPrice;
    [SerializeField] private int _id;
    [SerializeField] private bool _isStackable;
    [SerializeField] private bool _isEquipable;
    [SerializeField] private bool _isQuestItem;

    [SerializeField] private Property[] _requirements = new Property[2];
    [SerializeField] private RarityChances[] _chances;
    [SerializeField] List<Property> _mainProperties = new List<Property>();
    [SerializeField] List<PropertiesListContainer> _secondaryProperties = new List<PropertiesListContainer>();

    public List<Property> MainProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainProperties;
        }

        set
        {
            _mainProperties = value;
        }
    }

    public List<PropertiesListContainer> SecondaryProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return _secondaryProperties;
        }

        set
        {
            _secondaryProperties = value;
        }
    }

    public string ItemName
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemName;
        }

        set
        {
            _itemName = value;
        }
    }

    public ItemType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemType;
        }

        set
        {
            _itemType = value;
        }
    }

    public string ItemDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemDescription;
        }

        set
        {
            _itemDescription = value;
        }
    }

    public Sprite ItemUiImage
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemUiImage;
        }

        set
        {
            _itemUiImage = value;
        }
    }

    public int ItemPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemPrice;
        }

        set
        {
            _itemPrice = value;
        }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsStackable
    {
        get
        {
            return _isStackable;
        }

        set
        {
            _isStackable = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEquipable
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEquipable;
        }

        set
        {
            _isEquipable = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsQuestItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _isQuestItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _isQuestItem = value;
        }
    }

    public RarityChances[] Chances
    {
        get
        {
            return _chances;
        }

        set
        {
            _chances = value;
        }
    }

    public Property[] Requirements
    {
        get
        {
            return _requirements;
        }

        set
        {
            _requirements = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Есть своего рода база этих предметов, которая представляет собой лист EquipmentData:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="EquipmentDataBase", menuName = "EquipmentDataBase")]
public class EquipmentDataBase : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<EquipmentData> dataBase = new List<EquipmentData>();
}




И есть скрипт кастомного окна для редактирования этой базы:




using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class EquipmentEditor : EditorWindow
{
    EquipmentDataBase dataBase;
    EquipmentData _currentEquipmentData = null;
    EquipmentData _newItem = new EquipmentData();
    SerializedObject serializedBase;

    [MenuItem("ItemsEditors/Equipment")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow(typeof(EquipmentEditor));
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        dataBase = (EquipmentDataBase)Resources.Load("EquipmentDataBase");
        serializedBase = new SerializedObject(dataBase);
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        //start first column
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUILayout.MinWidth(300));
        for (int i = 0; i < dataBase.dataBase.Count; i++)
        {
            ShowEquipment(dataBase.dataBase[i]);
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Show"))
            {
                _currentEquipmentData = dataBase.dataBase[i];
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button("Delete"))
            {
                serializedBase.Update();
                if (_currentEquipmentData == dataBase.dataBase[i])
                {
                    _currentEquipmentData = null;
                }
                dataBase.dataBase.Remove(dataBase.dataBase[i]);
                serializedBase.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        //end first column

        //start second column
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUILayout.MinWidth(300));
        if (_currentEquipmentData != null)
        {
            ShowEquipment(_currentEquipmentData);
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        //end second column

        //start third column
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUILayout.MinWidth(500));
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
        _newItem.ItemName = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Name", _newItem.ItemName);
        EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("Desc");
        _newItem.ItemDescription = EditorGUILayout.TextArea(_newItem.ItemDescription, GUILayout.Height(50));
        _newItem.ItemPrice = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Price", _newItem.ItemPrice);
        _newItem.Id = EditorGUILayout.IntField("ID", _newItem.Id);
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        _newItem.ItemUiImage = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("", _newItem.ItemUiImage, typeof(Sprite), true);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            dataBase.dataBase.Add(_newItem);
            _newItem = new EquipmentData();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
        //end third column

        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    }


    public void ShowEquipment(EquipmentData item)
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal("box");
        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
        GUILayout.Label(item.ItemName);
        GUILayout.Label("Price: " + item.ItemPrice);
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("", item.ItemUiImage, typeof(Sprite), true);
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }


}
```

Проблема в том, что в течение сессии, то есть пока не перезапустил Unity все изменения в базе сохраняются, а вот как только перезапустишь юнити, она приходит в исходное состояние. При этом если данную базу редактировать через инспектор, то все отлично сохраняется и после перезагрузки.

Читал данный пост пока искал решение [Как сохранять данные asset'ов при их редактировании в EditorWindow?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545829/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-asset%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-editorwindow)

Можно ли как то по другому решить данный вопрос? И поможет ли это в моей ситуации вообще? Насколько я понимаю там надо как то это все через serializedProperty делать.

Comment: метод добавляющий ScriptableObject опустил, да? или создаешь их в другом месте? данные портятся в префабе?

Comment: Не совсем понял - что за метод, добавляющий ScriptableObject? У меня он уже существует, я загружаю его из папки Resources, вот этой строкой dataBase = (EquipmentDataBase)Resources.Load("EquipmentDataBase");  . Или я не так понял вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, вопрос решен - добавил в OnGUI следующее условие:

```
if (GUI.changed)
        {
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(dataBase);
            serializedBase.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
```